# Remove 2 lines before a particular string using sed

Tags: string, sed, grep

I have an xml file that I am trying to parse. It has somthing like

```
   **</data_item>
  </data_item>
</data_item>**
<xml version>
</data_item>
<some random text>
</data_item>
<some random text>

    **</data_item>
  </data_item>
</data_item>**
<xml version>

 **</data_item>
  </data_item>
</data_item>**
```

The lines highlighted in bold where there are 3 data_items, back to back (except the last set of 3) I want to delete two of them and retain only 1.. There are 7-8 of those occurrences and I am trying to use the string xml version to get to the two lines above it and delete them. Please help me with a sed one liner that does this.

Comment: I think this needs more info about structure, do you have multiple XML files concatenated or something?

Comment: Yes exactly! I have concatenated multiple xml files and so trying to delete redundant lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '/<\/data_item>/{N;/<\/data_item>$/{N;$!{s/\n//;D}}}' file
</data_item>
<xml version>
</data_item>
<some random text>
</data_item>
<some random text>

</data_item>
<xml version>

 </data_item>
  </data_item>
</data_item>
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed '
    /<\/data_item>/ {        # Look for lines matching this pattern
        N                    # Append the next line to pattern space
        /<\/data_item>$/ {   # If the line matches our pattern
            N                # Append the next line to pattern space
            $! {             # If it is not end of file
                s/\n//       # Replace the first new line with nothing
                D            # Delete up to first newline
            }
        }
    }
' file
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. If you are familiar with perl too, then any idea why integrating this line in a perl script throws an error? syntax error at script.pl line 20, near ";$!" Google said $ should be escaped in the scripts but it dint help

Comment: @user3614491 I think if you have a `perl` script, it would be better to do entirely in `perl` then to call `sed` from it. `perl` regexes are far superior than that of `sed`.

Comment: Oh I see ok. I was tempted to use these one liners inside of using perl. So just put this command inside backtick. Will figure it out. Thanks again